Console output can't print Chinese characters properly with maven unit test in Netbeans
My work environment is :
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 20
Java: 20.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.0.1+9-29
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 20.0.1+9-29
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; zh_CN (nb)
I try some unit tests which contain Chinese characters, and Netbeans console prints messy code like this:
messy codes output
this is my unit test code below:
        @Test
    public void printChinese(){
        System.out.println("测试");
    }

I've tried several ways to fix this problem,
such as add JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dstdout.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=utf-8 to environment variables.
modify pom, add this configuration:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dstdout.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=utf-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

modify /etc/netbeans.conf, add this argument:  -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
but all these failed.
But run this main() method, it works well:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("你好");
    }

running main() method works well
How could I fix this problem?

Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. BTW, you face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): '测试'.encode( 'utf_8').decode( 'gb18030') returns娴嬭瘯

Ok~thanks for helping.  I'll take care of that in the future.

After rebooting windows system, I run the tests again and get the expected result : Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dstdout.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=utf-8 Running com.********.***Test 测试.

After all the operations I mentioned in my question, I rebooted my computer, and then ran the unit test again, I got the expected output below :
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dstdout.encoding=utf-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=utf-8
Running com.********.***Test
测试

I'm curious about why the environment variables are not reloaded even if I restart Netbeans many times.
